# @microsoft/office-js module not found

Tags: office-js

I am trying to import office-js into a basic typescript test file. When I try and import the module like all other modules. I get `Cannot find module '@microsoft/office-js'`. Bellow is sample code of how I am trying to import it.

```js
import * as Office from '@microsoft/office-js'

function TestOffice() {
   console.log(Office);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally load office.js in an HTML file as described at [Accessing the Office JavaScript ...](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview?branch=refactor-coding-issues#accessing-the-office-javascript-api-library). The library needs to be loaded in a webview embedded in Office in order to initialize. But you might be looking for this: [Enabling Intellisense for a TypeScript project](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn).

Comment: I can't access the `Enabling Intellisense for Typescript project` link

Comment: What happens when you click the link?

Comment: I get `We are sorry, the page is forbidden.` page

Comment: I've fixed that link. Try it again.